# Why does concatenation work differently in these two samples?

Tags: python, concatenation

I am raising exceptions in two different places in my Python code:

```
holeCards = input("Select a hand to play: ")
try:
    if len(holeCards) != 4:
        raise ValueError(holeCards + ' does not represent a valid hand.')
```

AND **(edited to correct raising code)**

```
def __init__(self, card):
  [...]

  if self.cardFace == -1 or self.cardSuit == -1:
    raise ValueError(card, 'is not a known card.')
```

For some reason, the first outputs a concatenated string like I expected:

```
ERROR: Amsterdam does not represent a valid hand.
```

But, the second outputs some weird hybrid of set and string:

```
ERROR: ('Kr', 'is not a known card.')
```

Why is the "+" operator behaving differently in these two cases?

**Edit:** The call to init looks like this:

```
  card1 = PokerCard(cardsStr[0:2])
  card2 = PokerCard(cardsStr[2:4])
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see how the second error could arise.  I can't reproduce it.  Are you sure it's coming from the second block of code?  Could you perhaps also post the code that catches the exceptions?

Comment: len('Kr') == 2 would not fail the test.

Comment: Since one ValueError example is concatenation ("+") and the other ValueError is NOT concatenation (it uses ","), the question title is dead wrong.  Please fix it.

Comment: S.Lott's comment indirectly answered my question. In the context I used it, the comma in raise ValueError(card, 'is not a known card.') isn't operating as a concatenator, the way as it would in, say, print(card, 'is not a known card.') This was my error.

Comment: (con't) If you would turn your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"card" probably represents a tuple containing the string "Kr."  When you use the + operator on a tuple, you create a new tuple with the extra item added.

edit: nope, I'm wrong.  Adding a string to a tuple:

```
>> ("Kr",) + "foo"
```

generates an error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

It would probably be helpful to determine the type of "card." Do you know what type it is?  If not, try putting in a print statement like:

```
if len(card) != 2:
    print type(card)
    raise ValueError(card + ' is not a known card.')
```

Comment: I thought it was a string and, when I output type(card), I get <class 'str'>

Answer (score 8):

Um, am I missing something or are you comparing the output of

```
raise ValueError(card, 'is not a known card.')
```

with

```
raise ValueError(card + ' is not a known card.')
```

???

The second uses "+", but the first uses ",", which does and should give the output you show!

(nb. the question was edited from a version with "+" in both cases. Perhaps this question should be deleted???)

Comment: Yup, in the original code snippet, he was using '+' in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

This instantiates the ValueError exception with a single argument, your concated (or added) string:

```
raise ValueError(holeCards + ' does not represent a valid hand.')
```

This instantiates the ValueError exception with 2 arguments, whatever card is and a string:

```
raise ValueError(card, 'is not a known card.')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second case `card` is not a string for sure. If it was a string then `len('2')` would be equal to 2 and the exception wouldn't be raised, so check first what are you trying to concatenate, it seems something that added to a string returns something represented as a tuple.

I recommend you to use string formatting instead of string concatenation to create the error message. It will use the string representation (`__repr__`) of the object.

With string formatting:

```
>>> "%s foo" % (2)
'2 foo'
```

With string concatenation:

```
>>> 2 + " foo"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

And other question... what python version/implementation are you using? My cpython interpreter on Linux reports ValueErrors as `ValueError`, not `ERROR`...

Comment: I'm using Python 3.0 for Windows with IDLE.

Comment: (And, I should have added that the 'ERROR: ' is something I concatenated on the front, not the result of the exception raised.

Comment: You are not using concatenation in one of the cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you overloaded the `__add__()` somewhere in the code, that could be causing it to return a tuple or something?

Comment: Because it's possible to modify the behavior of the '+' operator dynamically.

Comment: I understand the question, but I'm not touching the definition of __add__.